# Is it possible to dynamically mutate columns (values in a column have other column names)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rlang

So I have one column of a dataframe which contains a value, which is equal to a different column name. For each row, I want to change the value of the column that is named.

```
df <- tibble(.rows = 6) %>% mutate(current_stage = c("Stage-1", "Stage-1", "Stage-2", "Stage-3", "Stage-4", "Stage-4"), `Stage-1` = c(1,1,1,2,4,5), `Stage-2` = c(40,50,20,10,15,10), `Stage-3` = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), `Stage-4` = c(NA, 1, NA, 2, NA, 3))

A tibble: 6 x 5
current_stage `Stage-1` `Stage-2` `Stage-3` `Stage-4`
<chr>             <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
Stage-1               1        40         1        NA
Stage-1               1        50         2         1
Stage-2               1        20         3        NA
Stage-3               2        10         4         2
Stage-4               4        15         5        NA
Stage-4               5        10         6         3
```

So in the first row, I would want to edit the value in the `Stage-1` column because the `current_stage` column has `Stage-1`. I've tried using `!!rlang::sym`:

```
df %>% mutate(!!rlang::sym(current_stage) := 15)
```

but I get the error: `Error in is_symbol(x) : object 'current_stage' not found`.

Is this even possible to do? Or should I just bite the bullet and write a different function?

Comment: You could `gather` into a longer format and work with it in rows

Comment: You can do this in a vectorized way with `base R`. `df <- as.data.frame(df);df[-1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), match(df$current_stage, names(df)[-1]))] <- 15`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within the `tidyverse`, I think using a long format with `gather` is the easiest way as suggested by [Jack Brookes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56228647/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-mutate-columns-values-in-a-column-have-other-colu#comment99077477_56228647):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  gather(stage, value, -current_stage, -rowid) %>%
  mutate(value = if_else(stage == current_stage, 15, value)) %>%
  spread(stage, value)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#>   rowid current_stage `Stage-1` `Stage-2` `Stage-3` `Stage-4`
#>   <int> <chr>             <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     1 Stage-1              15        40         1        NA
#> 2     2 Stage-1              15        50         2         1
#> 3     3 Stage-2               1        15         3        NA
#> 4     4 Stage-3               2        10        15         2
#> 5     5 Stage-4               4        15         5        15
#> 6     6 Stage-4               5        10         6        15
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>